# What is the need of Asynchronous Task

Tags: android

We have to use Asynchronous Task to start our new Activity on Tab Click event  but in the ListView or any view we can directly can start the new activity  Why?

Answer (score 7):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use
>   of the UI thread. This class allows to
>   perform background operations and
>   publish results on the UI thread
>   without having to manipulate threads
>   and/or handlers.
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a
>   computation that runs on a background
>   thread and whose result is published
>   on the UI thread.on the UI thread.

Basically you want to avoid that the loading process/device hangs when loading loads of data to the list initially, that's why you  make it async, outside the UI thread, so the user can  use the app while data is loading in the background.

Starting an activity is faster than loading lots of initial data into a long list view, especially if it's remote data from a remote server. Therefore the app you're looking at is probably using this here.

Comment: it's also true when opening a sqlite database, it's better to open it and populate the list in a background thread so you haven't a 1-2 seconds frozen UI..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some task in background at the same time you want to do another task at the forground.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
This link surely will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just try this one will help you.

http://xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html